# Storing input from text file

Tags: java

My question is quite simple, I want to read in a text file and store the first line from the file into an integer, and every other line of the file into a multi-dimensional array. The way of which I was thinking of doing this would be of creating an if-statement and another integer and when that integer is at 0 store the line into the integer variable. Although this seems stupid and there must be a more simple way.

For example, if the contents of the text file were:

```
4
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
2 4 1 3
3 1 4 2
```

The first line "4", would be stored in an integer, and every other line would go into the multi-dimensional array.

```
public void processFile(String fileName){
    int temp = 0;
    int firstLine;
    int[][] array;
    try{
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String inputLine = null;

        while((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null){
            if(temp == 0){
                firstLine = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
            }else{
                // Rest goes into array;
            }
            temp++;
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.print("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code of you trying to do this, and we can critique it and offer improvements.

Comment: Like I said, I have an integer that's set to 0, which gets updated, and an if-statement which when it's 0 stores that line in a variable. But it seems as if there's a way which would save me some lines of code.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Make sure to include the link. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: I edited the OP to include what I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm intentionally not answering this to do it for you. Try something with:

1. [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
2. A line that says something like `array[temp-1] = new int[firstLine];`
3. An inner `for` loop with another `Integer.parseInt` line

That should be enough to get you the rest of the way

Comment: I'm not looking for the code, just a less dumb way of doing this.

Comment: @user1327636: Your way of doing this is perfect. Your code is great, just put those two things in that one spot `//Rest goes into array`

Comment: @user1327636: I added the other piece to element #3

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could store the first line of the file as an integer, and then enter a for loop where you loop over the rest of the lines of the file, storing them in arrays.  This doesn't require an `if`, because you know that the first case happens first, and the other cases (array) happen after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you know how to use file IO.
I'm not extremely experienced, but this is how I would think about it:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
     //Read the number
     String number = inputFile.nextLine();

     if(!number.equals(" ")){
       //Do what you need to do with the character here (Ex: Store into an array)
     }else{
       //Continue on reading the document
     } 
  }
```

Good Luck.